# Is it possible to create a WPF application in Visual Studio 2010 which can sync with Windows Mobile 6.1 devices?

Tags: wpf, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I'm looking into creating a desktop and mobile app which can work together and sync data between each other using a local sql database on the phone and an sql database on the desktop (or possibly elsewhere).

Is it possible to do such a thing using Visual Studio 2010 for the desktop app and simply using Visual Studio 2008 for the mobile app (since I can't use 2010 for Windows mobile 6.1) or would there be unforseen issues I may run up against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Even if Visual Studio 2010 cannot talk directly to a Windows Mobile device, your application can. You will need the ActiveSync/WMDC API which will give you the Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity assembly.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384093.aspx